# Why is the eureka tech boost for siege tactics after owning two Bombards not working?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-gathering-storm

I have three bombards. The eureka requirement for Siege tactics is owning two bombards. But it has not been boosted.

I guess this is a bug. Is it know from before, and is there a workaround? Tried to reload the game from a save file, but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/mzwnhw/siege_tactics_eureka_not_triggering/) says that you actually need to use trebuchets instead.  Seems there was a patch made that changed this, but forgot to update the description:

> Eureka was updated in the last patch to be triggered with Trebuchets and not Bombards, but the description was not updated. Same with Replaceable Parts now needing Line Infantry and not Musketmen.

The same Reddit post references a Civilization forum post that leads to some [patch notes discussion](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/april-2021-update-patch-notes-discussion.669526/page-15#post-16081567):

> So as @hhhhhh posted, the tech boost trigger was changed to Trebuchets, but the text has not been updated - @Andrew Johnson [FXS]

[A Firaxis member](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/april-2021-update-patch-notes-discussion.669526/page-16#post-16081632) says the request was noted, but perhaps they have yet to still fix the description.

Thus, perhaps try trebuchets instead?

Comment: I have now confirmed that this is the correct answer

Comment: Sigh. I keep forgetting about this bug every time I play Babylon. And, by the time you've (re)discovered the bug when you have bombards, you can't build trebuchets anymore because bombards obsolete them. Your only hope to get the Eureka is that some city-state has a couple of trebs lying around that you can levy. And, if you can't get it, it also massively delays ballistics, the Eureka for which requires building forts, which requires Siege Tactics. Such an annoying bug to have stayed around this long.